# Safari is caching hard, I have to empty for each change in my css

Tags: safari, development

Does anybody know if there is a fix/workaround for Safari so it doesn't cache everything so hard. I'm solving a specific Safari bug and I have to empty the cache for each change I do. They removed the "disable cache" option so I'm wondering what you guys do.

Comment: Cmd/Opt/R not clearing enough?

Comment: @Tetsujin it does but it's not what I'm looking for. Developing frontend with Vite/Webpack it does "hot reloading" meaning it changes parts that has changed without reload, so to have to do Cmd/Opt/R defeats the purpose of it and slows down development.

Comment: Just explicitly reload your css by visiting its URL

Comment: @lhf it's the same as reloading with cmd/opt/r and kinda defeats the purpose of "hot reloading"? In chrome you can disable it, same as Safari had before.

Comment: Does private browsing not disable caching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this [article](https://geekflare.com/disable-cache-in-browsers/) that covers disabling cache when developing in Safari.

I'm on Safari v15.2. Don't quote me on this but I think it covers v14 as well.

1. Menu > select "Connect Web Inspector"
2. Network tab
3. There is now a icon button with a line cut through it (turns blue when active)

Images from the article

[image]

[image]